# How to create a dropdown menu from a link in a navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu that drops down from a link in a navigation bar when hovered over.  I'm not sure how to hide the list of links in the dropdown and then have them appear when the proper link is hovered over.  Any help would be appreciated.

My HTML thus far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Products</a> <!-- link that creates dropdown menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown">    <!-- dropdown menu list -->
                    <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS thus far

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: green;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```css
ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: green;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: green;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a> <!-- link that creates dropdown menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown">    <!-- dropdown menu list -->
                    <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to assign a CSS class to the hover event of the main nav elements, so that if a nav element is hovered and that nav element has a nested menu, display the nested menu on hover.

Here is a working demo.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: green;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

ul ul a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Products</a> <!-- link that creates dropdown menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown">    <!-- dropdown menu list -->
                    <li><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Technical</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Last</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```